# Prolog check list of numbers are in order

Tags: prolog

I would like to be able to take a list of numbers and get the largest sequence of numbers that are in order. For example:

```
?- in_order([1,2,3,4,5],N).
N = 5.                              % expected result

?- in_order([1,2,5,6,7,8,4],N).
N = 4.                              % expected result
```

I have so far produced some basic code that counts up the length of a sequence of numbers but once the list is empty, it back tracks, hence the number returned N, is the same as the first element in the list. I know that I need to stop back tracking but can't seem to do it. Would someone be kind enough to point me in the correct direction.

My code so far (all be it be a bit hacky):

```
in_order([],_) :-
   !.
in_order([H|T],N):-
   (  var(N), 
      N is H 
   ;  true
   ),
   H = N,
   M is N+1,
   in_order(T,M).
```

I do understand that my current solution would not work in the 2nd example given, and pointers for that aspect would again be helpful, as I'm not too sure how to tackle that aspect. I'm using SICStus Prolog.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather brute force solution to the problem :P ( I know I'll get criticized, but I couldn't resist playing with the higher-order predicates ).

```
my_prefix(List,Prefix) :- 
   append(Prefix,_,List).

my_suffix(List,Suffix) :- 
   append(_,Suffix,List).

my_sublist(List,Sublist) :-
   my_suffix(List,Suffix),
   my_prefix(Suffix,Sublist).

all_sublists(List,AllSublists) :- 
   findall(Sub,my_sublist(List,Sub),AllSublists).

good_list([]) :- 
   !.
good_list([H]) :- 
   !.
good_list([H1,H2|T]) :- 
   H1 is H2-1,
   good_list([H2|T]),
   !.

in_order(List,Length) :-
   all_sublists(List,AllSublists),
   findall(L,(member(Sublist,AllSublists),
              good_list(Sublist),
              length(Sublist,L)),
             InOrderSizes),
   max_list(InOrderSizes,Length).
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me call that relation `zs_maxInOrder/2`, it is based on [clpfd](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dclpfd.html)
and uses [reified constraints](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Reified-Constraints.html):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

zs_maxInOrder([]    ,0).
zs_maxInOrder([Z|Zs],N) :-
    zs_prev_n_max0_max(Zs,Z,1,1,N).            % use "lagging" 

zs_prev_n_max0_max([]     ,_ ,_ ,M ,M).
zs_prev_n_max0_max([Z1|Zs],Z0,N0,M0,M) :-
    Z1 #= Z0 + 1 #<=> B,                       % with SWI-Prolog use `(#<==>)/2`
    N1 #= N0 * B + 1,
    M1 #= max(M0,N1),
    zs_prev_n_max0_max(Zs,Z1,N1,M1,M).
```

Let's see it in action using SICStus Prolog 4.3.1:

```
?- zs_maxInOrder([1,2,3,4,5],N).
N = 5 ? ;
no
?- zs_maxInOrder([1,2,5,6,7,8,4],N).
N = 4 ? ;
no
```

What about corner cases?

```
?- zs_maxInOrder([1],N).
N = 1 ? ;
no
?- zs_maxInOrder([],N).
N = 0 ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt fails because you are mixing different things. When you write

```
N is H
```

You are basically outputting one of the elements of the list. This is something you don't want to do in any case. Also the base case is wrong, it should be "An empty list has an ordered sequence of zero".

Try to use an "accumulator" argument that keeps track of the consecutive elements terminating with the current head H.

Comment: Thanks as soon as I read this: "An empty list has an ordered sequence of zero" I knew what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> "An empty list has an ordered sequence of zero".

Thanks for that. It put me on the right track (I think)

This is my solution so far:

```
in_order([], _, 0).
in_order([H|T], Prev, N):-
  % Split the list
  in_order(T, H, M),
  % Increment the expected Head value
  H1 is Prev + 1,
    (
      H = H1,
      N is M + 1
    ;
      M1 is M + 1,
      format('M1 is ~w~n', [M1]),
      N is 0
  ).
```

I've added the format so that I can see what is being printed at the final stage, and I get the values 1 and 4 for input [1,2,5,6,7,8,4] - which is correct. The predicate returns 2 (the last length of the sequence), but when I backtrack to try and get more answers I do not get the values 4 or 1. I think I'm pretty close to the answer, any additional final help would be appreciated.

many thanks

Comment: try to keep the current longest sequence in accumulator